# Bulk collect into multiple columns

Tags: oracle, plsql, bulk-collect

I can define a one-column table and bulk collect into it. i.e:

```
create type table_of_strings as table of varchar2(200);

DECLARE
    l_tab table_of_strings;
BEGIN
    
    select emp_name bulk collect into l_tab from emp;

END;
```

But how do I collect into multi-column tables? Say:

```
create type emp_row as object (emp_name varchar2(200), emp_salary Number);
create type emp_table as table of emp_row ;

DECLARE
    l_tab emp_table ;
BEGIN
    -- I have tried things like this but would fail:
    select (emp_name, emp_salary) bulk collect into l_tab from emp;
    select emp_name, emp_salary bulk collect into l_tab from emp;
    select * bulk collect into l_tab from (
         select emp_name, emp_salary  from emp);

END;
```

Thank you in advance!
Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
select emp_row(emp_name, emp_salary) bulk collect into l_tab from emp;
```

---

Here's a slightly modified example based on Scott's schema.

```
SQL> CREATE TYPE emp_row AS OBJECT (emp_name VARCHAR2 (200), emp_salary NUMBER);
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> CREATE TYPE emp_table AS TABLE OF emp_row;
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
```

PL/SQL code:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_tab      emp_table;
  3     l_max_sal  NUMBER;
  4  BEGIN
  5     SELECT emp_row (ename, sal)
  6       BULK COLLECT INTO l_tab
  7       FROM emp
  8      WHERE deptno = 10;
  9
 10     FOR i IN l_tab.FIRST .. l_tab.LAST
 11     LOOP
 12        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
 13           l_tab (i).emp_name || ' - ' || l_tab (i).emp_salary);
 14     END LOOP;
 15
 16     SELECT MAX (emp_salary) INTO l_max_sal FROM TABLE (l_tab);
 17
 18     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Max salary = ' || l_max_sal);
 19  END;
 20  /
CLARK - 2450
KING - 5000
MILLER - 1300
Max salary = 5000

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks, @littlefoot! Just what I needed. For future people:
 I needed to add l_current_row := l_tab(i); and putline ( ...l_current_row.emp_name...) to please my datagrip compiler. But that was easy enough to find out myself.

Comment: You're welcome; I'm glad you made it work.

Comment: I have one more syntax issue: I want to work with emp_table as if it was an actual table. However, I miss the syntax. For example, how do I get the maximum salary?
I have tried versions of select max(emp_salary) into l_max_sal from table(l_tab);

Comment: Have a look at edited code; that's line #16 (which is what you did, so - yes, that's it).

Comment: Thanks. So my simplified example worked... sorry, I should have tried myself... I tested something with decode and would not believe that the issue was there.